# How to integrate int variable in a string?

Tags: c, string, int

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i=100;
    char temp[]="value of i is **** and I can write int inside a string";
    printf("\n%s\n",temp);

}
```

I need to print value of `i` inside a string. So that I will get the output as:

```
value of i is 100 and I can write int inside a string
```

What should I write at the place of **** or how should I change this code to get the output as above? I don't want to use `printf` to print this output.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, the main function returns an integer, so begin with `int main()` and finish with `return 0;`

Comment: @TheBigH Don't use `int main()`, use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: don't use the void in the parameter list, as that is not the correct format.  Note: the () parameter list means any number of parameters, including none.  It is the same with sub functions.  the prototype will have the (void); but the actual declaration of the function will have a simple ()

Comment: use the suggested answers to place the complete text into a buffer, then use fputs() to print the string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to 'print' a string into a char array, like `printf` prints it to the screen:

```
char temp[256];
sprintf(temp, "value of i is %d and I can write int inside a string", i);
```

Note that you need to make sure your buffer is large enough! Or use [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to specify the maximum string/text length, so you do not write outside of the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("value of i is %d and I can write int inside a string\n",100);
```

If you don't want to do this then go for

```
char buf[200];
int i=100;
snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"value of i is %d and I can write int inside a string",i);
```

Comment: OP says: _I don't want to use printf to print this output_

Answer (score 2):

A safe way of doing this is to use

```
char temp[256]; /*allocate some storage, currently large enough for the text and a 64 bit int*/
snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "value of i is %d and I can write int inside a string", i);
```

`sizeof(temp)` is 256. `snprintf` will stop writing data to `temp` once it reaches that size; allowing for a null-terminator.

I'd discourage using `sprintf` as it is unsafe given that it can overrun the supplied buffer: `snprintf` has been part of the C standard library for a while now.

**And**, change that prototype to `int main()` **and** return a value. 0 normally indicates succes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{

    int i=100;
    char temp[]="value of i is %d and I can write int inside a string";
    printf(temp,i);

}
```

Try this.

Comment: `printf("value of i is %d and I can write int inside a string", i);` ?